# Should I capture return value by value or by r-value reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

If I have a function that returns some object like

```
std::vector<int> foo()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    return v;
}
```

then what's the difference between saying

```
std::vector<int> &&v = foo();
```

and

```
std::vector<int> v = foo();
```

?

(Why) would I prefer either over the other?

(I suspect this might be a duplicate question, but I couldn't find the right search terms.)

Comment: does this one help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618506/is-it-possible-to-stdmove-objects-out-of-functions-c11/13618587#13618587

Comment: @billz: Yeah, it basically seems to say that they do the same thing when you're returning an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading one of these (and thus knowing that it's doing something reasonable) requires understanding about temporaries and how binding a temporary to a reference extends the lifetime of the temporary. The other is:

```
std::vector<int> v = foo();
```

Always pick the one that's easier to understand. It also works just as well if `foo` returned a `const&` or a `&&`, whereas storing it by `&&` would only work if it returns by value or by `&&`.