# Move std::vector of std::unique_locks

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, locking, move-semantics

I have a data structure consisting of few 'blocks'. For each block I have mutex. I want to implement a method that locks entire data structure and move this lock to calling function. Here's my code:

```
std::vector<std::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>> lock_array() 
{
    std::vector<std::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>> locks;
    for(size_t block = 0; block < BLOCK_COUNT; ++block)
    {
        locks.push_back(std::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>(mutexes[block]));
    }
    return std::move(locks);
}
```

And if I call it in such way, will my array still be locked?

```
void some_method()
{
    auto locks = lock_array();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI - the std::move technically isn't required because the compiler can do return value optimization and move the result out implicitly.

Comment: @MikeWeller: Besides RVO not being mandated, to return by copy, a copy ctor needs to be present, wether optimized out or not.

Comment: RVO is not such thing that I can rely here, because it's not guaranteed that it will be used

Comment: locks still locked because they acquire lock during construction and will destroy only when locks go out of scope. and `std::move(locks);` won't help here as Mike mentioned.

Comment: But you don't need the `std::move` anyway. It inhibits RVO, and it doesn't add anything: if you just `return locks`, you will either get RVO, or a move.

Comment: @juanchopanza is it guaranteed by the standard that RVO or move will be used for sure?

Comment: if you are confused by rvo, copy, move, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618506/is-it-possible-to-stdmove-objects-out-of-functions-c11/13618587#13618587

Comment: @EvgenyEltishev: Yes, the standard guarantees that it will be either moved, or the move will be elided. C++11 12.8/32 describes how the return expression is treated as an *rvalue* if possible, so that the move constructor will be selected.

Comment: It is guaranteed that move will be used if RVO hasn't been used, and if the types involved have move constructors.

Comment: @plasma  a move ctor is enough.

Comment: @Yakk: a move ctor does not copy.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: But return values are moved if possible, so a move constructor is enough to return a value from a function. I'm not sure why you're talking about returning by copy, since the question is about returning an uncopyable (but movable) type.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, a move ctor does not copy.  And the sky is blue.  And leopards have spots.  Despite these and other interesting facts, a move ctor is enough to return a local variable from a function, and that move ctor can be elided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Moving a `unique_lock` will preserve the lock, and moving the vector should not affect the locks at all. You could verify this:

```
void some_method()
{
    auto locks = lock_array();
    for (auto const & lock : locks) {
        assert(lock.owns_lock());
    }
}
```

Also, note that you don't need `std::move` when returning; return values are moved anyway (unless the move is elided).

Answer (score 1):

You transferred `locks` out of `lock_array()` function, compiler should use [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) or **move** locks out of `lock_array()`, otherwise you will get compiler error as unique_lock is moveable but not copyable.

locks still locked because they acquire lock during construction and will destroy only when locks go out of scope. Your **transfer action** won't destroy locks.

§ 30.4.2.2

> An object of type unique_lock controls the ownership of a lockable object within a scope. **Ownership of the lockable object may be acquired at construction or after construction, and may be transferred, after acquisition, to another unique_lock object. Objects of type unique_lock are not copyable but are movable.**